# Worker process behind web-service... what ingredients to use

Tags: wcf, websphere, msmq

I have the following recipe: a web-service (SOAP) needs to be able to receive a lot of requests in a short time. They should be queued for asynchronous processing. So in the background, there should be a worker that takes the requests from the queue and does a job on them. Some of the jobs may even encounter unavailable (third party) resources, in which case the job should be retried later.

The question I have is: what are my ingredients? WCF, MSMQ, WAS? What is the basic structure of setting this up?

Comment: Have you looked at NserviceBus? http://www.nservicebus.com/docs/Samples/AsyncPages.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's important whether you'll store them, in MSMQ or in SQL or somewhere else - any backstore you choose will require an additional **service** to dequeue and process the data. A SQL database could have some advantages over pure MSMQ, for example you could store some additional information with your data and then retrieve some statistics over time, how many requests were processed and what was their internal structure. This could help you in future to further tune the processing pipeline.